# Quartz scheduler and job 'firing' a second early

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, batch-processing

Can anyone advise? I have a job which runs on the hour, every hour, and which is controlled in a Java webapp by Quartz 1.8.3.

What I'm seeing though is that Quartz seems to start the job a second early sometimes. But as there's no apparent pattern to this it is difficult to correct.

My code is:

```
Scheduler_Job sj = Scheduler_Job_DB.get(1);       
   sj.setJobRunning(Valid.TRUE);
   Scheduler_Job_DB.update(sj);
   SQLDateTime currPollDateTime = SQLDateTime.getSQLDateTimeNow();
```

Where currDateTimeNow is being set to 17:59:59 when it should be 18:00:00.

The cron trigger for the Quartz job is 0 0  * * * ?

The method SQLDateTime.getSQLDateTimeNow(); simply gets the current count in milliseconds and converts it into java.sql.Date and java.sql.time elements as follows:

```
public static SQLDateTime getSQLDateTimeNow() {
    long milliSecs = DateTime_Utils.getTimeInMilliseconds();
    Date date = new Date(milliSecs);
    Time time = new Time(milliSecs);
    SQLDateTime sqldt = new SQLDateTime(Date.valueOf(date.toString()), Time.valueOf(time.toString()));
    return sqldt;
}
```

Class SQLDateTime simply has two variables as follows:

```
private Date sqlDate;
private Time sqlTime;
```

And is convenient when using dates and times stored in the database in yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss format.

In 99.9% of cases this is fine but I don't understand why the job seems to fire one second early?

I should add that upgrading to Quartz 2.x is not an option.

Any ideas anyone?

My solution is to keep it simple. So if the Quartz job fires at a given hour, and if I have the job's details stored in a database table, then I can also store the current run time and date, e.g. YYYY-MM-DD 18:00:00.

So the job fires, it reads the details including the date and time from the database, and makes all the updates for 18:00:00.

Then at the end of the job, the current run time and date get incremented by an hour and are written back to the database for use as the next run date and time. So 18:00:00 becomes 19:00:00 and the date stays the same unless the job is running at 23:00:00.

So everything is in synch and there's no playing with milliseconds.

It sounds good in theory anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the different clocks are marginally offset, so when the quartz scheduler starts on **18:00:00 005** it could be that the database still thinks its **17:59:59 980**.

If its really an issue to you, you might want to sleep the thread some hundred millis so its always correct.

Comment: I was wondering about this: but surely the clocks are both taking the date and time from the underlying Win 7 server? And it is an issue because various updates are scheduled and these are being missed when the problem occurs.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that being 100% correct at any time. Also it could be that one part uses millis and the other uses nanos so when the time is '17:59:59 9991' quartz says: okay that 1800 but the database disagrees. Why don't you use the java Date so everything uses the same time?

Comment: I suspect you you may be right in thinking that the two clocks might be ever-so-slightly out of synch. I use the JavaSQLDateTime class because it is convenient and works very well in the application at hand. But delaying the thread by one second if the time is not to the hour might be an answer.

Comment: I'm going to post this to Quartz and see what they think as well.

Comment: Or simply converting the time to a String and reformatting mins and secs if they are not 00.

Comment: But it will leave the time at 17:00:00 rather than 18:00:00.

Comment: then configure it to match __:59:59.* then the hour doesn't matter to you.